# is there a way to give class method as a key parameter (sort/min/..) in python?

Tags: python, key

It's common to do something like

```
min(my_list, key=lambda x: abs( x - 5))

foo(my_list, key=lambda x,y: abs(x-y))
```

Suppose my_list is a list of some **MyClass** object, and I wonder if I could define the key function in the MyClass and use it when I call min or foo.

**Edit**

I should have been more clear..

Is there a way to achieve the following using the **MyClass** method instead of using lambda here?

```
foo(my_list, key=lambda x,y: abs(x.value-y.value))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'MyClass({0.value})'.format(self)
...     def key_function(self):
...         return -self.value
... 
>>> my_list = [MyClass(2), MyClass(1), MyClass(3)]
>>> my_list
[MyClass(2), MyClass(1), MyClass(3)]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda mc: mc.value)
[MyClass(1), MyClass(2), MyClass(3)]
>>> min(my_list, key=lambda mc: mc.value) # by attribute
MyClass(1)
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda mc: mc.key_function()) # by method call
[MyClass(3), MyClass(2), MyClass(1)]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=MyClass.key_function) # using unbound method
[MyClass(3), MyClass(2), MyClass(1)]
```

**UPDATE**

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'MyClass({0.value})'.format(self)
...     def delta(self, other):
...         return abs(self.value - other.value)
... 
>>> def foo(a_list, key):
...     return [key(a, b) for a, b in zip(a_list, a_list[1:])]
... 
>>> my_list = [MyClass(1), MyClass(10), MyClass(100)]
>>> print foo(my_list, key=lambda x, y: abs(x.value - y.value)) # Using lambda
[9, 90]
>>> print foo(my_list, key=MyClass.delta) # Using unbound method
[9, 90]
```

Comment: suppose I do clustering and it takes a function to compare two values to group them.  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cluster/1.1.0b1

Comment: wow, surprising to see the first parameter gets assigned to self and second one to the next method paraemter.  I'll try that with the function I'm working with.

Comment: It's an unbound method. For example `'abc'.find('b')` is equivalent to `str.find('abc', 'b')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
min(my_list, key=operator.methodcaller('keymethod'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here's an example where `MyClass == str`:

```
L = 'a', 'B', 'c'
print(min(L)) # -> B
print(min(L, key=str.lower)) # -> a
```